# How to regulate the load node?

Tags: power, transmission-line, matlab

I was given the next assignment, but I dont know what to do.
From the system showed there must be a regulation at the PQ node (3rd). But the course is starting and I have no idea what to do, it is supposed to be equations that regulate this, but I wasnt given none.
The system is
[image]

The conditions are :
the tension must be regulated at the PQ node,so it can support:
a)  100 MW, 60 Mvar (at the load)

b)  140 MW, 90 Mvar (at the load)
So, intuitively, this can be done via playing with the controls and running the solve system, but whats the math behind it.
Im asking for advise of what to do, not the solution of it.

When using 100MW/60MVAR the generators run well
[image]

but when the 140/90 load is applyed the gen2 wents off.
[image]

So besides of cutting off load, what more can be done?
Is there a way to balance the load so the generators can support it?
Thanks in advance

PD.I have seen this can be done in matlab/simulink but what are the values/parameters usually taken?

Comment: Can you add caps at the load bus to supply var locally?

Comment: It is supposed to be allowed, but it was suggested to be another way to do so. But how can I do that?

Comment: I don’t know what software package you are using. You should just be able to add as a known impedance on the load bus.  This would put it directly into the YBUS matrix for that bus and not as element of load P or Q.

Comment: Another idea, modify one of the line impedances to have lower inductive reactance.  This would simulate series compensation (which is just  series capacitor).